# Updating table in database using string from database?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to update one column of the database using the string in the listbox which exactly match the string in the database but it works only for the string with no spaces. For example if I have product like "Iphone" in listbox, I get that string and pass to Update() method below, it works. 
But if I use the "Samsung Galaxy S3", as choosen item from listbox, visual studio throws me the error that there is no such row.

I am sure that it is because of the space in between that word. How can I solve the problem.

**Code to update the database**

```
 public string Update(string product)
            {
                // Create connection object
                int ix = 0;
                string rTurn = "";
                OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                try
                {
                    oleConn.Open();
                    string sql = "UPDATE [Product] SET [Quantity]=[Quantity] - 1 " + " WHERE [Product Name]= " + product;
                    OleDbCommand oleComm = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);

                    oleComm.Parameters.Add("@product", OleDbType.Char).Value = product;

                    ix = oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (ix > 0)
                        rTurn = "Stock Updated";
                    else
                        rTurn = "Update Failed";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    oleConn.Close();
                }
                return rTurn;
            }
```

**Code to pass string of each item to the Update() method.**

```
public void UpdateStock()
        {
            foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
            {
                string result = Update(listBoxItem.ToString());
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string sql = "UPDATE [Product] SET [Quantity]=[Quantity] - 1 " + " WHERE [Product Name]= '" + product + "'";
```

Try this instead :)

You need to identify product as a string :)

Comment: You can also do like Ivan G saids :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
string sql = "UPDATE [Product] SET [Quantity]=[Quantity] - 1 " + " WHERE [Product Name]= " + product;
```

to

```
string sql = "UPDATE [Product] SET [Quantity]=[Quantity] - 1 WHERE [Product Name]= ?";
```

You are adding parameter `@product` but you are not using it. Concatenating queries is not a good practice, it leaves you open to the SQL injection attacks.